# Strengthening Bertrand's postulate using the prime number theorem

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory

In its page on [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) Wikipedia says

> It follows from the prime number theorem that for any real 
>   $\varepsilon >0$ there is an $n_0 > 0$   such that for all $n > n_0$ 
>   there is a prime $p $  such that $n < p < ( 1 + ε )n$  .

I need to quote this result for  $\varepsilon = 1/2$. I'd like a reference more formal than Wikipedia.

Comment: Why don't you cite the reference that very source that Wikipedia used:  G. H. Hardy and E. M. Wright, An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, 6th ed., Oxford University Press, 2008, p. 494.

Comment: @fleablood Of course. I missed that reference. Post as an answer, or I can delete the question as too narrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ariticle on wikipededia cites that with a foot note (as of the time I write this) #8 refering to: G. H. Hardy and E. M. Wright, An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, 6th ed., Oxford University Press, 2008, p. 494.

> [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results)
>
> It follows from the prime number theorem that for any real $ {\displaystyle \varepsilon >0}$ there is a ${\displaystyle n_{0}>0} $ such that for all ${\displaystyle n>n_{0}} $ there is a prime $ {\displaystyle p}$ such ${\displaystyle n<p<(1+\varepsilon )n}$. It can be shown, for instance,
>   that
>
> ${\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {\pi ((1+\varepsilon )n)-\pi
> > (n)}{n/\log n}}=\varepsilon ,} $[8]
>
> [8]G. H. Hardy and E. M. Wright, An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, 6th ed., Oxford University Press, 2008, p. 494.

Comment: This is pretty unreadable. I doubt that Hardy and Wright says “for any real $\epsilon > 0 > \epsilon > 0\epsilon > 0$, for example (and it doesn’t get better). Can you edit the quote so it doesn’t look like a copy/paste from some non-LaTeX source? Even an image of the relevant Hardy and Wright page would be better than this.

Comment: It *is* a copy and paste from a non-LaTeX source! I thought the was clear from context.

Answer (score 2):

tersely worded, but Dusart gives, for $x \geq 396738,$ a prime between $x$ and
$$ x \left( 1 + \frac{1}{25 \log^2 x} \right)  $$

[I think it was on the arxiv, let me find it](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442).

Yes, this is Proposition 6.8.

For your fixed target $3x/2,$ you may fill in the smaller numbers with the table of maximal prime gaps at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Numerical_results . I went through the thing once by machine, for $p \geq 11$ and $p < 4 \cdot 10^{18},$ we get gap $g < \log^2 p.$