# Does at least one prime $p$ exist in the upper range [n/2,n] for n even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For example, let $n=20$.

The lower range [$0$,$\frac{n}{2}$] has primes $p$ = $2,3,5,7$.

The upper range [$\frac{n}{2}$,$n$] has primes $p=$ $11,13,17,19$.

For any even number, does there exist at least one prime $p$ in [$\frac{n}{2}$,$n$]?

It seems true but is there a proof?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852944/strengthening-bertrands-postulate-using-the-prime-number-theorem

Comment: Very interesting! Never heard about Bertrands Theorem. So at least there's a prime $p$ in that range $[\frac{n}{2},n]$. Thanks.

Comment: @vengy This result can be extended : For every $\epsilon>0$, there is a positive integer $n_0$, such that for every $n\ge n_0$, then range $[n,n(1+\epsilon)]$ contains at least one prime number.